# Updating table data from submission array cause all row to because the same data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am pulling data from the database and displaying in a form.

I want the values to be edited and then the form when resubmitted will update the data in the table based on the corresponding row, however its updating the table based on the index value 4 **only**. All other data for the `teamid` is being replaced with the data in the arrays for the `4` index.

Here is the `var_dump` when the form is submitted ( this shows the modified data so its submitted correctly so assume its an issue with the loop )

```
array (size=12)
      'teamid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'activity' => string 'Mill 1' (length=6)
      'activity2' => string 'Enter Details' (length=13)
      'info' => string 'Auto process' (length=12)
      'info2' => string 'Enter Details' (length=13)
      'wsno' => string '1' (length=1)
      'labour' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string 'Admin' (length=5)
          1 => string 'QC Manager' (length=10)
          2 => string 'Supervisor' (length=10)
          3 => string 'Team Leaders' (length=12)
          4 => string 'Line Operators' (length=14)
      'hours' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
          3 => string '8' (length=1)
          4 => string '8' (length=1)
      'noworkers' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '2' (length=1) << CHANGED THIS FROM 1 TO 2
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
          3 => string '1' (length=1)
          4 => string '3' (length=1)
      'rateperhour' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '11.00' (length=5)
          1 => string '10.00' (length=5)
          2 => string '9.00' (length=4)
          3 => string '8.50' (length=4)
          4 => string '8.00' (length=4)
      'totalcost' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '22' (length=2) << THIS IS THE NEW CALCULATED VALUE
          1 => string '10.00' (length=5)
          2 => string '18.00' (length=5)
          3 => string '68.00' (length=5)
          4 => string '192.00' (length=6)
      'addteam' => string '' (length=0)
```

The value I changes was on the first index (`0`) -as No Workers to 2 and the value is correct when submitted

```
if(!isset($_GET['team'])) {
    $teamid = 1;
} else {
    $teamid = $_GET['team'];
}
$teamlq = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `teams` WHERE `teamid` = '$teamid'");
$teamlr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($teamlq);
$actq = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `teams` GROUP BY `activity` ASC");
$act = mysqli_fetch_assoc($actq);
$infoq = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `teams` GROUP BY `info` ASC");
$info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($infoq);
$wsq = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `workstation_costing` GROUP BY `wsno` ASC");
$ws = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wsq);
if(isset($_POST['addteam'])) {
    $labour[] = $_POST['labour'];
    $hours[] = $_POST['hours'];
    $noworkers[] = $_POST['noworkers'];
    $rateperhour[] = $_POST['rateperhour'];
    $totalcost[] = $_POST['totalcost'];
    $maxrows = 5;
    $i = 0;
    $info = $_POST['info'];
    if($_POST['info'] == 'other') {
        $info = $_POST['info2'];
    }
    $activity = $_POST['activity'];
    if($_POST['activity'] == 'other'){
        $activity = $_POST['activity2'];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    do {
        $labour = $_POST['labour'][$i];
        $rateperhour = $_POST['rateperhour'][$i];
        $hours = $_POST['hours'][$i];
        $noworkers = $_POST['noworkers'][$i];
        $totalcost = $_POST['totalcost'][$i];

        $insert = mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE `teams` SET `activity` = '$activity',`info` = '$info',`wsno` = '$_POST[wsno]',`labour` = '$labour',`rateperhour`='$rateperhour',`hrsengaged` = '$hours',`noworkers`='$noworkers',`totalcost`='$totalcost' WHERE `teamid` = '$_POST[teamid]'");
        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
        $i++;
    }while ($i < $maxrows);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the table showing `teamid` 1 which the form is updating 
( before form submission )
[image: Before form submission]

[image: After form submission]

Comment: Can you try to clean up the code? (remove all unrelated lines, indentation...)? What exactly did you change and where it is not happening? your question is not clear

Comment: And your loop use the `UPDATE` with the same `$_POST[teamid]` so it override all the rows... I think you should have `ID` column in this table

Comment: its meant to update the same team id as there are multiple labours for each teamid
How can I get it to update each item in the arrays with the corresponding data ?

Comment: ahh good point .. I'll give that a try and come back

Comment: Yep that did it .. added an auto id to the table and created an array in the form based on each rowid and no works perfectly .. many thanks
If you want to create an answer based on your suggestion I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that inside the loop you do:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE `teams` SET `activity` = '$activity',`info` = '$info',`wsno` = '$_POST[wsno]',`labour` = '$labour',`rateperhour`='$rateperhour',`hrsengaged` = '$hours',`noworkers`='$noworkers',`totalcost`='$totalcost' WHERE `teamid` = '$_POST[teamid]'");
```

but you never update the `$_POST[teamid]` so in each iteration you update all the fields with that `$_POST[teamid]` with the current data of the loop -> this cause to the table has only the last loop values for all the row with that `teamid`.

In order to overcome that you can add `ID` column to your table and in the loop update the row by its `ID` rather then the `teamid` -> this will result in updating 1 row at each iteration